# height во всю высоту экрана

Tags: jquery, css, вёрстка

Подскажите, есть ли возможность на css сделать следующее: задать для контейнера `max-height`, а внутренний блок чтобы был `height:100%` относительно контейнера. При этом контейнер всегда был в центре по вертикали.

Верстаю такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то тут не то...

Answer (score 7):

---

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Поддержка FlexBox [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

---

А также рекомендую прочесть про `vw` и `vh`

[www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative0)

[css-tricks.com viewport-sized-typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Поддержка [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

---

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 100vw;*/
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  min-height: 450px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.content .block {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #ffc0cb;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте через `position: absolute;` и `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

```css
.div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 80%;
  background: #555;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: Дополню своим, похожим вариантом: https://jsfiddle.net/kqabhsad/